# If $xy=yx$ in group $G$, then $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am showing that if for some group $G$, $xy=yx$ for every $x, y \in G$ then

$$(xy)^n=x^ny^n.$$

I claim this holds by induction on $n$. So base case if $n=1$, we have

$$(xy)^1=xy=x^1y^1$$

as needed. Then suppose for $k$ that we have

$$(xy)^k=x^ky^k$$

And we want to show

$$(xy)^{k+1}=x^{k+1}y^{k+1}$$

But we can expand

\begin{align}
(xy)^{k+1} &= (xy)^k(xy) && \text{def of exponent} \\
&=x^ky^kxy && \text{by inductive hypotheses} \\
&=x^kxy^ky && \text{as $xy=yx$ thus $x$ commutes with all $k$ $y$'s}\\
&=x^{k+1}y^{k+1} && \text{def of exponent}
\end{align}

and we are done by induction. The only step I am shaky about is the third equality. Do I separately need to show if $xy=yx$ then $y^kx=xy^k$ as well or?

Comment: Yes, first show $y^kx=xy^k$ by induction.

Comment: thanks :-) !! Will do!! @DietrichBurde

Comment: Despite this being an FAQ, I'm struggling to find a duplicate . . .

Comment: Found one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/620209/104041

Comment: If the hypothesis is that the group is an Abelian group, then there's no issue with interchanging $x$ and $y^k$.  However, it's also true that in any group, if $x$ and $y$ commute (but not necessarily all pairs of elements commute), then $(xy)^n = x^n y^n$ for all $n$.  For that, you will indeed need to prove the intermediate result that $x^k$ and $y$ commute.

Comment: Alternatively, consider that $(xy)^{n+1}=x(yx)^ny$.

Comment: This is a fine quality question. OP has a proof worked out for their larger objective and has presented it. They are asking for feedback about one particular step in this proof of theirs:  "do I separately need to show...?"  They are not asking for a proof that $(xy)^k=x^ky^k$. For what it's worth, yes you should show that using some additional argument. If it were clear enough to leave out that additional argument, then the original exercise is equally clear.

Comment: @2'59'2 thanks :-) !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show $y^kx=xy^k$ by induction. Another trick is to take an $x$ and $y$ off each end so that $(xy)^{n+1}=x(yx)^ny=x(xy)^ny=x(x^ny^n)y=x^{n+1}y^{n+1}$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Answer (score 2):

To finish the inductive step, $y^kx = y^{k-1} (yx) = (y^{k-1} x)y = xy^{k-1}y=xy^k$.

As this is a low quality question, I will add my two cents into how to think about these operations. Since groups are associative and commutative, we can just rearrange the variables in any order we want.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.